# Can I develop crossplatform VR app on UE4 for SteamVR (HTC Vive + Valve Index) and Oculus Quest (2)?

Tags: unreal-engine4, virtual-reality, oculus, steamvr

I'm new in VR development and I try to choose engine which I'll study and use for my first app.

After some research I prefer UE4 over Unity but I can't understand can I create full cross-platform app that can be used on for example Vive Index and Oculus Quest 2 in standalone mode?

As I know Unity give you this opportunity, but what about UE4?

Answer (score 0):

As of Unreal 4.27, the OpenXR VR template will work out of the box for Valve Index, Quest 2, and other headsets.
Here's a link to the docs of the new VR template, which has a list of devices: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/Resources/Templates/VRTemplate/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).